# Alternate to BaseTreeModel in gxt 3.0

Tags: gwt, extjs, gxt

I was using **GXT 2.2.4** and now moved to **GXT 3.0**, but unable to find the import directory of **BaseTreeModel** which was available at **com.extjs.gxt.ui.client.data.BaseTreeModel** location in previous version.

*Can someone tell me which directory i should include or do it has some alternate in 3.0.*

Answer (score 0):

Your DTO should `extends TreeStore.TreeNode<MyDTO>`. This interface requires that you implement a

`public List<MyDTO> getChildren()`

method which return a list of the childs and a

```
 public MyDto getData() {
    return this;
  }
```

method, which returns the MyDTO instance.